# call a function with argeparse option and pass it a sys.argv element

Tags: python, argparse

i have two functions

```html
p={}
def a(arg2):
  #do something 

def b(arg2):
  #do something with arg 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='*******')
    parser.add_argument('-a',dest=a(p),action='store')
    parser.add_argument('-s',dest=b(sys.argv[3]), action='store')

    args = parser.parse_args
```

However when i run script.py -s JohnDoe
it dosen't run the function b whith the argument JohnDoe whats the problem?

Comment: No,no, that's not how you use `argarse`, or any of the other standard parsers. First read and practice with examples from the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
args = parser.parse_args
```

is missing the `()` that runs the method.  Otherwise you just end up assigning the bound method to `args`.  It doesn't parse anything.

The `dest` parameter is supposed to be a string.  It's the name of the attribute in args.  Without the `dest`, `script.py -s JohnDoe` should produce

```
In [858]: setattr(args, 's', 'JohnDoe')    # done during parsing
In [859]: args                          # display the args variable
Out[859]: Namespace(s='JohnDoe')
In [860]: args.s
Out[860]: 'JohnDoe'
```

which you could use in a

```
b(arg.s)
```

It's the `action` parameter that determines what is done with the newly parsed value.  The default is to store it in `args` as I demonstrated.  With a custom `Action` class it is possible to do fancier stuff, but that's an advanced topic.

```
dest=b(sys.argv[3])
```

sets the `dest` to what ever values `b` returns, which may be `None`. If `b` was defined as

```
def b(arg):
    return arg
```

then `b(sys.argv[3])` would produce `JohnDoe`, and you'd get an `args` that looks like:

```
In [863]: args
Out[863]: Namespace(JohnDoe='JohnDoe')
```

That's a cute trick but probably not what you wanted.